# Where data will be stored in Mongo DB by default, when we use mongoose with Express

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am new to Node JS technology. I have 3 basic doubts.

1. In my nodeJS application, I connected to mongodb using mongoose. But I did not mention any collection name. But data is getting saved when I sent data from Form as expected. I want to know that in which collection it will be stored by default. How to see the stored data.
2. how to mention specific collection name using mongoose if we want to save data in a particular collection.

3.Generally If we want to use any middleware in our app, we connect that 
  middleware using app.use() right? but in mongoose case, we do not add that 
  to app.use(). but still we can use the mongoose functionality.
could anyone please tell how it is possible.

Thanks a lot  in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How Mongoose interacts with MongoDB is described [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html).

It has this example:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: 'string', size: 'string' });
var Tank = mongoose.model('Tank', schema);
```

and mentions that

*The first argument is the singular name of the collection your model is for. Mongoose automatically looks for the plural version of your model name. Thus, for the example above, the model Tank is for the tanks collection in the database.*

`model()` takes a third argument where you can rename the collection:

```
var Tank = mongoose.model('Tank', schema, 'collectionname');
```

The collection gets made when `model()` is called.

`app.use()` is used for Express middleware. Mongoose isn't really that, which is why you're not using `app.use()` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This should probably be broken into multiple questions and you should probably show some code.  That said, I'll take a crack at it.

Collection names are defined when you model your schema.  So let's say you have:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: String
});
```

And then you later will tell mongoose to model it:

```
mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

You'll have a collection called "users" in the database you're connecting to in your `mongoose.connect()` call.

Regarding middleware, Express middleware is specifically functions that you want to fire during the request/response cycle.  You can still call code (e.g. mongoose) outside that cycle, and generally you'll connect to the database when the application starts and then read or save to it in either middleware or in your route handlers.  For example, you might have a route like:

```
const User = mongoose.model('User');
app.get('/users', (req, res, next) => {
  User.find({}, (err, users) => {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.send(users);
  });
});
```

In that case, you've got a route handler that calls mongoose through the User model previously defined.